# Binding data from session to drop down list asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my web application, I have added a dropdownlist for the nav bar.

There I want to load some data from the database.

So in the Home Controller, I have used a view bag option.

```
ViewBag.MyBranch_Id = new SelectList(BranchList, "Id", "Name");
```

In this view, I called it as

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyBranch_Id", null, new { @class = "form-control js-dropdown js-MyBranch", @Id = "Branch" })
```

But the issue is this dropdown I created on the layout view. So when I navigate to another view, then the view bag data error occurs. (Because when I moved to another controller, the view bag method is on the `HomeController` `Index` Action. So then the View bag Data become null.)

So then I load the data to the session. So on the layout page, I called the session data as

```
 @{
     List<SelectListItem> MyBranch = Session["MyBranch"] as List<SelectListItem>;
   }
```

and the dropdown menu

```
 @Html.DropDownList(MyBranch, null, new { @class = "form-control js-dropdown js-MyBranch", @Id = "Branch" })
```

**MyBranch** has an error . Cannot `convert selectListItem to string`.

I cant use `DropDownListFor` because this has no model to assign the session data.

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace Your code in view like below:

```
SelectList MyBranch = Session["MyBranch"] as SelectList;

@Html.DropDownList("MyBranch", MyBranch, new { @class = "form-control js-dropdown js-MyBranch", @Id = "Branch" })
```

You should pass MyBranch as selectlist in dropdownlist
I wish that helps!